# Android as WiFi access point using Wifi rather than 4g

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, android-networking, chromecast

I need to know if this is even possible and if it is how I would go about doing this.

I have a laptop, android phone, and Google ChromeCast HDMI adapter. When I am at home and on the same network as the ChromeCast I am able to broadcast by browser window to the Chromecast and thus watch what I am doing on my TV.

I need a way that when I am away from home and on a network that blocks devices from talking to one another to be able to do the same thing.

In order to do this I believe what I need to be able to do is have my Samsung sIII connect to a WiFi point where it has internet access, then for my computer and ChomeCast to connect to my phone on a completely different class c where they are able to access the internet but also talk to one another regardless of if the external network permits it or not.

I can do this by using the phones built in hotspot, but I don't want to use my phones data plan if there is a network I can connect to in order to use their internet.

In addition to using this while I am with clients to broadcast my browser screen, when I am travelling with my family I would like to be able to stream from my Netflix account however most hotels I have stayed in won't let the chrome device connect to my computer because of the AP isolation.  Again, it would be nice to connect to the hotel wifi to stream netflix but to let the chrome device connect to the phone as it's access point so the phone can talk to the ChromeCast.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to get a small wifi router that you can easily carry with you when you go to a, say, hotel? You can set up your own little wifi network without any AP isolation issues and connect your phone and chromecast devices to that and do what you want.

Comment: Not sure what version of android you're running, but mine will tell me data usage (not sure if it breaks it down by wifi/cell network), if it does, then perhaps just give it a try, take a snapshot of your data usage then connect to a network, create your AP, and stream for 30 seconds (should be enough to give you some real data), check your usage again.